# JavaScript not being served in Django template

Tags: javascript, django

I have configured static files in my project as follows..

**settings.py**

'''Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images),

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/'''

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', 'static_root')

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', 'static_dirs'),
)

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', 'media')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
```

.................. other url confs

```
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

I am using `{% load staticfiles %}` in my template and JavaScript is attached using script tags with `{% static 'js/bootstrap.js' %}` as my src.

CSS is working all fine. But the JavaScript does not seem to work and I cannot figure out why. Please Help.

Comment: Do you have a bootstrap.js file in your app's static directory?

Comment: Yes. and it is placed at the URL static/js/bootstrap.js

Comment: What do you mean by "JavaScript does not seem to work" ? Does http://localhost:port/static/js/bootstrap.js respond ?